# How to check when input exceeds row in column of two dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am making a connect 4 board game in c. My problem is trying to make the logic to calculate if the array has been filled up.

I have tried changing my logic multiple times, but only using if statement. I am basically clueless at this point

```
// Returns TRUE if the specified column in the board is completely full
// FALSE otherwise
// col should be between 1 and COLS
int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col ){

    // check the TOP spot in the specified column (remember column is between 1 and COLS, NOT 0 and COLS-1 so you'll need to modify slightly


// if top spot isn't empty (0 is empty) then the column is full, return 1
    if (board[col -1][0]!=0){
    return(1);
    }
// otherwise, return 0
    return(0);

    //return column_full_lib ( board, col ) ;
}
```

Expected result is when board is filled, it should return 0:
When it is not filled up as in column 2, it should return 1

```
[x][][][][]
[o][x][][][]
[o][o][][][]
[x][o][][][]
[o][x][][][]
[x][x][][][]
```

Comment: You can use a counter to count num of elements of x'th column. if cnt[x]<num_of_rows return 1 otherwise 0. Update the value of cnt[x], each time you update your grid.

Comment: Why not initialize all elements of the array to zero. Then you can iterate over each row for each column and if a zero is encountered, return 1 from within then loop. If no zero is encountered in a column, return zero at the end after all loops complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Returns TRUE if the specified column in the board is completely full
// FALSE otherwise
// col should be between 1 and COLS
int column_full ( int board[ROWS][COLS], int col ){

    // check the TOP spot in the specified column (remember column is between 1 and COLS, NOT 0 and COLS-1 so you'll need to modify slightly


// if top spot isn't empty (0 is empty) then the column is full, return 1
    if (board[0][col - 1]!=0){
    return(1);
    }
// otherwise, return 0
    return(0);

    //return column_full_lib ( board, col ) ;
}
```

I have made some changes to your code. I am not sure if this is exactly what you want but this makes more sense.

```
[x][][][][] 
[o][x][][][]
[o][o][][][]
[x][o][][][]
[o][x][][][]
[x][x][][][]
```

The problem seems to be that you are accessing wrong indices. Although it depends on how you inputted it and how you are using it. The way your board looks like in your question, it seems if you want to access topmost element of a column, it should be like

`board[0][col - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
/* When Game is started you have to fill the board with value 0.
then update with non-zero value. then count the total value of the colum over all rows.
 */

  int column_full ( int board[ROWS][COLS], int col ){
   int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=ROWS; i++){
        if(board[1][COLS] != 0)cnt++;
    }     
    return (cnt != ROWS); //return 1 if column is fill otherwise return 0 
  }
```